# Reaction wheel for linear motion

Tags: angular-momentum, propulsion

Reaction wheels can rotate a spacecraft only around its center of mass (see torque); they are not capable of moving the spacecraft from one place to another (see translational force) [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel)
What if we have a changing center of mass? for example: weight that can move inside of a spacecraft in space and two reaction wheels on far ends that turn on and off based on where is the center of mass. Wouldn't spacecraft slowly creep in one direction?
[image]

white circles are reaction wheels and black is the center of mass (weight)

Answer (score 2):

Pick an inertial reference frame in which the spacecraft’s centre of mass is momentarily stationary. In the absence of an external force the COM will *always* be stationary in this reference frame because of conservation of momentum. You can move the parts of the spacecraft around relative to one another, but you can never move the centre of mass in this reference frame.

Of course, you can throw one small part of the spacecraft very fast in one direction, and the rest of the spacecraft will then move slowly in the opposite direction. But what you have invented then is a thruster.

Comment: wait, but they use reaction wheels to rotate satellites in space, or i got something wrong?

Comment: @BorisT Reaction wheels can rotate a spacecraft only around its COM; they are not capable of moving the spacecraft from one place to another. And you cannot move the COM around. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel

Comment: Sure, spacecraft rotates around COM. I am not sure you can't move COM, imagine inside a spacecraft two containers (black on my photo) that are connected by pump that can move fluid(water) from one container to the other, doesn't that change COM of entire spacecraft?

Comment: @BorisT No, COM doesn't move. Water moves in one direction, rest of spacecraft moves in opposite direction, COM is stationary. Water stops moving, rest of spacecraft stops moving, COM is still stationary. All due to conservation of momentum.

Comment: ok i am confused now. If you have an hollow object and weight at one place and then on the other place doesn't that mean that COM has changed as well?

Comment: @BorisT The COM can only move if an external force acts on the weight. If the weight is moved by an internal force (e.g. a spring pushing against the box) then the reaction force pushes the box in the opposite direction and the COM does not move. Once again, conservation of momentum.